# MariaDB columnstore table join innodb table

Tags: sql, mariadb, innodb, columnstore

I know that this kind of join is supported, but it doesn't work for me for the next case;

Given the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE person_cs(
    firstName VARCHAR(255),
    lastName VARCHAR(255),
    address TEXT,
    age INT,
    stateId INT
) ENGINE=ColumnStore;

CREATE TABLE person_inno(
    firstName VARCHAR(255),
    lastName VARCHAR(255),
    address TEXT,
    age INT,
    stateId INT
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE states (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    state TEXT NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`person_cs` and `person_inno` are the same entries table (12M) but different engine.

`states` is lookup innodb table with 50 entries;

So the query `select count(*), state from person_inno p join states s on p.stateId = s.id where p.age > 31 group by s.state;` works greate (although it take more then 5 minutes with indexed columns)

once I try `select count(*), state from person_cs p join states s on p.stateId = s.id where p.age > 31 group by s.state;` it fails with the error:

`ERROR 1815 (HY000): Internal error: MCS-2058: Unknown Error`

Any idea why?

I worked with MariaDB columnstore as docker with latest version.

Comment: I don't see any indexes in the table definition.  Does `person_inno` have this composite index?  `INDEX(age, stateId)`

Comment: @RickJames I didn't showed the indexes query, trust me, I defined them.

Comment: `INDEX(age, stateId)` is _not_ the same as `INDEX(age), INDEX(stateId)`.  Since this is a common misconception, I had to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Please report [as a bug](https://jira.mariadb.org), MCOL project. Even if its intended for some reason a better message is needed.

2058 in ColumnStore code seems to indicate:
`2058    ERR_DISKAGG_OVERFLOW1 The hash function used produces a lot of hash collisions (1).`

Comment: Opened https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MCOL-5557 - thanks